# Java double - Only zeros after certain decimal place

Tags: java, precision

I have written a program, which should brute force the square root with a lot of decimal places. That is working fine, but only until the 50th decimal place is reached. When for example using 12 as the input for the method, after the 50th decimal place, only zeros appear. I am pretty sure that this is not the expected output.

I don't think it is a precision problem, because I am already using [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)s for the calculations. Here is my current code:

```
static String solve(double num, int decimalPlaces) {
    BigDecimal toAdd = new BigDecimal("1.0");
    BigDecimal currentNumber = new BigDecimal("0.0");

    for(int i = 0; i <= decimalPlaces; i++) {
        currentNumber = currentNumber.setScale(i);

        System.out.print(currentNumber.toPlainString() + "          >> " + i + "\r");
        while(Math.pow((currentNumber.add(toAdd).doubleValue()), 2) <= num) {
            currentNumber = currentNumber.add(toAdd);
        }

        toAdd = toAdd.divide(BigDecimal.TEN);
    }

    return currentNumber.toPlainString();
}
```

Current Output (when `num = 12` and `decimalPlaces = 80`):

```
3.46410161513775460839781317190499976277351379394531250000000000000000000000000000
```

Do you have any ideas why that is and possible solutions?

Comment: You are using `BigDecimal` but *also* `double` values during your calculation. That means that the parts that use `double` will also be affected by its limited precision. For example the `Math.pow()` call operates on `double` values. You should use `BigDecimal.pow()` instead. And just remember: as soon as you call `doubleValue()` anywhere, chances are you've lost most of the benefits of using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: You would want to do all the calculations using `BigDecimal` but you need to keep in mind that `BigDecimal` wants you to define a (maximum) precision and a rounding rule to keep that precision, especially for multiplications and divisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Eliminate any use of floating-point types `double`/`Double` and `float`/`Float` if you want accurate results with a wide range/precision.
- Use only `BigDecimal` objects.

## Use only `BigDecimal`, without `double`

The moment you involve a `double` primitive value or a `Double` object, you [loose accuracy due to floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) math.

Your method takes a `double` as its first argument named `num`. If you want accuracy and range/precision, take a `BigDecimal` instead.

```
static String solve( BigDecimal num, int decimalPlaces ) { … }
```

Call that method in this manner. Notice we pass the twelve as a string literal rather than as a numeric literal.

```
String result = Whatever.solve ( new BigDecimal( "12" ) , 80 ) ;
```

You cannot use comparator syntax with objects, such as `<=`. Your line `while(Math.pow((currentNumber.add(toAdd).doubleValue()), 2) <= num)` should instead call the method [`BigDecimal::pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow(int)).

Minor issue… Your line `System.out.print( currentNumber.toPlainString()` should be `System.out.println( …`, calling [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) rather than `print`.

This might be close to the code you seek. I am no math whiz so I cannot vouch for the logic.

```
static String solve ( BigDecimal num , int decimalPlaces )
{
    BigDecimal toAdd = new BigDecimal( "1.0" );
    BigDecimal currentNumber = new BigDecimal( "0.0" );

    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= decimalPlaces ; i++ )
    {
        currentNumber = currentNumber.setScale( i );

        System.out.println( currentNumber.toPlainString() + "          >> " + i + "\r" );
        while ( currentNumber.add( toAdd ).pow( 2 ).compareTo( num ) <= 0 )
        {
            currentNumber = currentNumber.add( toAdd );
        }

        toAdd = toAdd.divide( BigDecimal.TEN );
    }

    return currentNumber.toPlainString();
}
```

See this [code run live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jmqrmW).

```
0          >> 0
3.0          >> 1
3.40          >> 2
3.460          >> 3
3.4640          >> 4
3.46410          >> 5
3.464100          >> 6
3.4641010          >> 7
3.46410160          >> 8
3.464101610          >> 9
3.4641016150          >> 10
3.46410161510          >> 11
3.464101615130          >> 12
3.4641016151370          >> 13
3.46410161513770          >> 14
3.464101615137750          >> 15
3.4641016151377540          >> 16
3.46410161513775450          >> 17
3.464101615137754580          >> 18
3.4641016151377545870          >> 19
3.46410161513775458700          >> 20
3.464101615137754587050          >> 21
3.4641016151377545870540          >> 22
3.46410161513775458705480          >> 23
3.464101615137754587054890          >> 24
3.4641016151377545870548920          >> 25
3.46410161513775458705489260          >> 26
3.464101615137754587054892680          >> 27
3.4641016151377545870548926830          >> 28
3.46410161513775458705489268300          >> 29
3.464101615137754587054892683010          >> 30
3.4641016151377545870548926830110          >> 31
3.46410161513775458705489268301170          >> 32
3.464101615137754587054892683011740          >> 33
3.4641016151377545870548926830117440          >> 34
3.46410161513775458705489268301174470          >> 35
3.464101615137754587054892683011744730          >> 36
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447330          >> 37
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473380          >> 38
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733880          >> 39
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338850          >> 40
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388560          >> 41
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610          >> 42
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856100          >> 43
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050          >> 44
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610500          >> 45
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105070          >> 46
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050760          >> 47
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620          >> 48
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076200          >> 49
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762070          >> 50
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620760          >> 51
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207610          >> 52
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076120          >> 53
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620761250          >> 54
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207612560          >> 55
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125610          >> 56
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620761256110          >> 57
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207612561110          >> 58
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125611160          >> 59
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620761256111610          >> 60
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207612561116130          >> 61
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125611161390          >> 62
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620761256111613950          >> 63
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207612561116139580          >> 64
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125611161395890          >> 65
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620761256111613958900          >> 66
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207612561116139589030          >> 67
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125611161395890380          >> 68
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620761256111613958903860          >> 69
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207612561116139589038660          >> 70
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125611161395890386600          >> 71
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620761256111613958903866030          >> 72
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207612561116139589038660330          >> 73
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125611161395890386603380          >> 74
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620761256111613958903866033810          >> 75
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207612561116139589038660338170          >> 76
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125611161395890386603381760          >> 77
3.464101615137754587054892683011744733885610507620761256111613958903866033817600          >> 78
3.4641016151377545870548926830117447338856105076207612561116139589038660338176000          >> 79
3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125611161395890386603381760000          >> 80
result: 3.46410161513775458705489268301174473388561050762076125611161395890386603381760007
```

Comment: The `System.out.print()` is because I want it to edit the line (`\r`). In the actual code is a delay in the for-loop to make it build the result ;). Anyways your hints made it work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are converting your big decimal to double in `Math.pow((currentNumber.add(toAdd).doubleValue()), 2)`, and here you loose precision. Just use method `pow` on BigDecimal itself to produce the power.

This is the corrected code that seems to work for me:

```
static String solve(double num, int decimalPlaces) {
    BigDecimal toAdd = new BigDecimal("1.0");
    BigDecimal currentNumber = new BigDecimal("0.0");
    BigDecimal numBD = BigDecimal.valueOf(num);

    for (int i = 0; i <= decimalPlaces; i++) {
        currentNumber = currentNumber.setScale(i);

        System.out.print(currentNumber.toPlainString() + "          >> " + i + "\r");
        while (currentNumber.add(toAdd).pow(2).compareTo(numBD) <= 0) {
            currentNumber = currentNumber.add(toAdd);
        }

        toAdd = toAdd.divide(BigDecimal.TEN);
    }

    return currentNumber.toPlainString();
}
```

As an additional benefit, this code is actually somewhat simpler.

Comment: Sorry, I did that in Groovy. One second, I'll correct the code to be proper Java code